# Can I use both the bibliography and bibTeX?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I want to use my hand-written thebibliography section and additionally use the perks of the BibTeX. Is it possible to use both of these systems?

Here is the text of my .tex file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
In the paper of A \cite{paperA}. \\
In the paper of B \cite{paperB}.


\begin{thebibliography}{3}
\bibitem{paperA}
Blah.
\bibliography{TESTbibfile}

\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

That is the screenshot of what I see:
[image]
I do also have a bib file, here it is:

```
@article {paperB
author = {B},
title = {blah2}
}
```

Comment: Welcome, you can use both, but i don't recommend it. You would need to rewrite your manual bibliography to match the visual output of the bibliographystyle (which is missing in your document and hence you get errors by bibTeX). It would be better to invest the time in adding your entries to the BibTeX database.

Comment: The code snippet you've posted definitely won't compile correctly: The `\bibliography` directive initiates and terminates an instance of a `thebibliography` environment; it's not legal to have nested `thebibliography` environments. I suppose you could proceed as follows: First, use`BibTeX` to create a `thebibliography` environment with various `\bibitem` entries. It'll be housed in the file named `\jobname.bbl`. Second, if you're ok with the contents and don't have to rerun BibTeX, you could then hand-edit the bbl file to either add further entries or to modify the existing, formatted entries.

Comment: @Mico but it is basically just a nested list. Having a section command inside a list is a bit odd and having nested lists isn't what is being looked for. But all in all, no problem to mix them up. It just doesn't give a proper result.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the bibliography from bibtex?

Comment: the point of bibtex is to correctly sort the bibliography, and to consistently style all the entries in the style specified by the bibliography style. If you patch in some hand written entries at the start then the sorting will be wrong and the style inconsistent so you lose all the benefits of using bibtex.

Comment: People, you have convinced me. I am going to BibTeX. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments

Comment: I think this is a legitimate question, since sometimes one works with BibTeX but has to collaborate with co-authors who do use BibTeX. Then the question is how to combine these two methods efficiently.